# How can i get only some fields from many to many relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to get some fields from a relationship that i have defined.

If i find all the ingredients of a menu like this:

```
$ingredients = auth()->user()->menu->ingredients();
```

I want to send to the view only the id and name fields of each ingredient, something like this:

```
$ingredients = auth()->user()->menu->ingredients()->withColumns('id', 'name');
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values), it will allow you to get data as:

```php
[
   1 => 'John',
   15 => 'Samu',
   16 => 'Harry',
]
```

If you want this, you have to write:

```php
$ingredients = auth()->user()->menu->ingredients()->pluck('name', 'id');
```